# ¿Cómo ejecutar un stored procedure de SQL Server en Python con pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql

Un gusto saludarles. Los pongo en contexto, tengo un código de SQL que debe ejecutarse todos los días y los datos deben ser guardados en un Excel, es un código bastante grande con tablas bastante grandes también. El código debe ejecutarse sábados, domingos, días de asueto, es decir, no puede dejar de correr ningún día. Una de mis ideas es construir un stored procedure en SQL y luego ejecutarlo desde Python para poder guardar las tablas en archivos de Excel automáticamente.

Este es un ejemplo del stored procedure con el que estoy probando momentaneamente, el query original tiene muchas tablas que se construyen a partir de joins con otras tablas de la base de datos, el output final son 4 tablas distintas que deben ser guardadas.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PythonTest
AS

set nocount on

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test_Python1
SELECT *
INTO Test_Python1
FROM table1

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test_Python2
SELECT *
INTO Test_Python2
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id

SELECT * FROM Test_Python2
SELECT * FROM Test_Python1

GO;
```

No hay problemas con el stored procedure, sin embargo, en Python sí hay ciertas cosas que no se están haciendo bien, logro conectarme al servidor donde están todas las tablas que necesito pero no obtengo los resultados que deseo, este es mi código:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


 conn_str = (r'DRIVER={SQL Server};' r'SERVER=MyServer;' r'DATABASE=Data1;' 
             r'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

 conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
 cursor = conn.cursor()

 storedProc = "exec PythonTest"
 cursor.execute(storedProc)

 row = cursor.fetchone()
 while row:
    print(str(row[0]) + " : " + str(row[1] or '') )
    row = cursor.fetchone()

 conn.close()
 cursor.close()
```

El código de Python funciona bien, sin embargo, esto solo me arroja una tabla y es la de **Test_Python2** porque es a la que se le aplica primero el **select** en el stored procedure. ¿Hay alguna manera de obtener ambas tablas y guardarlas en dataframes distintos?

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas usar `nextset()` para pasar al siguiente set de resultados, por ejemplo:

```
# Leemos el primer recorset
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
   print(str(row[0]) + " : " + str(row[1] or '') )
   row = cursor.fetchone()

# Intentamos pasar al segundo, si existe lo leemos
if cursor.nextset():
   row = cursor.fetchone()
   while row:
      print(str(row[0]) + " : " + str(row[1] or '') )
      row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Creo que además se necesita en el sp un `SET NOCOUNT OFF` antes del select final (además del `ON` al comienzo) y posiblemente tampoco venga mal un `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`

Comment: Funcionó bastante bien para dos selects, tengo una pregunta, esto funcionaría en caso de que sean 3 o más selects? Con respecto al set nocount off, si fueran más de 3 selects cómo debería aplicarse? Gracias

Comment: Si, debería funcionarte para `n` recordsets, el `set nocount off`  debería ir antes del primer `select` que retorna el SP.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, me has ayudado un montón.